# React + SSR: Correct way to handle a component that needs to fetch data first

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

I currently have a React app that I'd like to use SSR with. All but one component is pretty much static content, making SSR super easy. Everything but the component is rendered just fine and well right now.

My question is how do I go about rendering this component that needs to first get data? Because it's a complex SVG that gets rendered my line of thinking is that having it "update" once data comes in is a bad move, and it would be better for it to just not exist in the absence of data (with an error message).

So here's my plan: I can add a prop to the component to pass in data from a parent rather than keep it as internal state only. So if data is passed, no fetch request in the component is necessary. From there what I can do is take the static bundle output of the app and, when the page is requested, the server will request the proper data just as the component would. Once the data is received, the server can grab the component from the bundle with regex, add the data as a prop, render the component, and stick it back in with the rest of the already rendered static content.

Is this the correct way to do this? It feels a bit complicated, but that might just be how it's done. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuitions are correct. In current React (17.0), it's quite cumbersome to do SSR with data-fetching inside components.

What needs to be achieved on a conceptual level is that all data dependencies need to be known upfront, ie. before calling ReactDOM's render. This way, one can access the data in a synchronous manner which allows to do one-pass render on a server.

I don't quite follow your idea to "grap the component from the bundle with regex". One way of solving the data dependency problem is to inject the data into React tree from the root component (ie. `ReactDOM.renderToString(<App componentStaticData={data} />)`) and make the data-dependent component aware of the fact that it can just grab the data from there instead of doing (asynchronous) call. It's important to note that useEffects are not executed on the server.

Another idea to grab all the data dependencies is to do two-pass render. First one is used as a way to collect all resources used, then we await their completion and inject them as static data into send pass.

Third way is to use one of the React frameworks that provide SSR out of the box. You can have a look at (among many others) Next.js or Gatsby. Depending on your setup, this might be easiest or the hardest way to achieve SSR.

Comment: The regex is because I'm using React to produce a bundle but to server the client I'd need to avoid doing any JSX transforms as I don't want to have to setup babel for that. So quite literally getting the transpiled component and rendering it. But thanks, I needed that conceptual help to understand what needed to happen.

Comment: catchergeese can you help me in solving my problem similar to this one. Link is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72220011/is-there-any-method-to-overcome-the-error-of-hydration-ui-in-next-js-while-using .... I am having trouble setting up in my react & next app